# Slack bot - registering to a message-event not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, slack-api, bolt, slack-bot

We created a Slack app using Bolt and Javascript.
We wanted to listen to messages coming from the Slack app. We went to the api.slack.com and added `message.app_home` event

[image]

According to the documentation we should add an event to the Bot for `message` and check if the the event.type is `app_home`

We did it as follow:

[image]

We add a new message in the Slack app:

[image]

The listener function just logs the message, but it never gets called:

[image]

Is it something with the Bolt or I am not implementing it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

We figured it out.

We had to add `message.im` event to the ‘Subscribe to bot events’ section.
The message.app_home is deprecated and won’t work for new apps created after 2021.